Equivalent Sets of Order Axioms for the Real Numbers
I'm currently studying Königsberger Analysis 1, 6th Edition (in German) , which defines the Order Axioms for the real numbers like this:

Translation from German :
The Order of $\mathbb{R}$ is defined by some numbers being positive (notation $>0$), these obey following three axioms:
\begin{align}
&\text{A1) }\,\, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}: a>0 \,\, \dot \lor \,\, a=0 \,\, \dot \lor \,\, -a>0 \\
&\text{A2) }\,\, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}: (a>0 \land b>0) \implies (a+b>0 \land ab>0) \\
&\text{A3) }\,\, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}: \exists n \in \mathbb{N} : n-a >0 \qquad \text{(Archimedean Axiom)}\\
\end{align}
However from a different source, I found these Order Axioms:
\begin{align}
&\text{B1) }\,\, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}: x=y \,\, \dot \lor \,\, y<x \,\, \dot \lor \,\, x<y \\
&\text{B2) }\,\, \forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}: ((x<y \land y<z) \implies x<z) \\
&\text{B3) }\,\, \forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}: (x<y \implies x+z < y+z) \\
&\text{B4) }\,\, \forall x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}: ((x<y \land 0 <z) \implies xz <yz) 
\end{align}

Whilst assuming that B3) is true, I managed to prove the equivalence of a few statements. However, I couldn't figure out how to prove B3), given the statements of A.
Furthermore A3) seems out of place, as I didn't need it in any of my proofs, and it's not even an axiom, since it can be proven from the continuum property. What does axiom A3 contribute to the equivalence of A and B?

To me these look more like the additional axioms of an ordered field, not the definition of an order. itself.

You should check the textbook further.
What you have given is to "introduce" the Positive Numbers.
Using that , we have to move on to the actual "Order" , which might go something like this :
Let $P$ (Positive Numbers) be non-empty Set where $a,b \in P \implies a+b \in P \land ab \in P$
Every $a$ will make Exactly one of these true : $a \in P , a=0 , -a \in P$ (Trichotomy)
Define :
When $(a-b) \in P$ then $a \gt b$ or $b \lt a$
When $(a-b) \in P \cup \{0\}$ then $a \ge b$ or $b \le a$
B3 can then go like this :
$x \gt y \implies (x-y) \in P$
Here $(x-y) = (x+z)-(y+z)$
Hence $(x+z)-(y+z) \in P$
Hence $(x+z) \gt (y+z)$
We are using $P$ (Positive Numbers) to make claims on all numbers.
Archimedean Property is axiomatically assumed in your text book , maybe because there was no axiomatic treatment of Natural Numbers.
Proving Archimedean Property can be easily accomplished in various ways when we have the Axioms for Natural Numbers.
[[ It is just claiming that there is some $n \in N$ larger than the real number $x$ ]]
Archimedean Property is useful (though not necessary) to get intuition to apply later.
On other words , B Axioms do not require Axiom A3.
